# React-Native white-space even if i use KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native, react-redux, keyboard, styles

I have an issue with my TextInput. When i'm trying to enter text the keyboard open and add white space between my input.
I try in Android and I have no soluce.

KeyboardAvoidingView not work same with KeyboardAwareScrollView because I use my scroll in vertical.

Im using React 17.0.2 React-Native 0.66.3 and React-Navigation 5.9.8

If someone can help me thanks !

link for screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKGZi.png + https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xz5X.png

```
return (
<SafeAreaView>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={styles.keyboard}
    enable
    //keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          horizontal={true}
          pagingEnabled={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
          scrollIndicatorInsets={{ top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10 }} // ios
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
              <Image
                style={styles.icon}
                source={require("../images/icon/folder.jpg")}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.input1}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Name"
              />
                </Text>
              )}
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Reference"
              />
                </Text>
              )}
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Code"
              />
                </Text>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
```

My style :

```
container: {
 width: screenWidth,
 alignItems: "center",
 backgroundColor: "#FAFBFB",
 height: screenHeight
},
keyboard: {
 flex: 1
},
input: {
 marginBottom: "10%"
},
input1: {
 flex: 2,
 justifyContent: "center",
 alignContent: "center",
 width: "80%",
 paddingBottom: "15%",
 marginBottom: "10%"
},
```

Comment: I also have this issue did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your Textinput always has a value variable that is a piece of state (useState hook), and an onChange function (your piece of state setter) that sets the piece of state to the new form value on change.

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const MyTextInput= () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Default Text");
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={onChangeNumber}
        value={number}
        placeholder="placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};


export default MyTextInput;
```

Comment: Yes I know it's on purpose to display less code. The error I am trying to solve is Keyboardavoidingview